# How do I solve this exponential equation on Excel Solver?

Tags: excel, solver, exponential

100e^0.25*y = 97.5

Solving for y

Using Excel Solver

I tried using empty column entry for y in 'By changing cells' and Set objective function as LHS of above equation (empty column entry in equation included) equal to value of 97.5 in solver.

It gives no solution

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you not do the arithmetic in Excel? Surely you can get `y = ...` and just run the math in Excel? (FYI `e` is `Exp(1)` in Excel).  Also, it's unclear if we are to do `100e^(.25*y)` or `100 * e^.25 * y` ...it's been a while, but is that the same as `y = (log(e)(.975))/.25`?  where log is "log .975, base e"

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need the solver. Just re-arrange your formula to solve for Y.  Since `y = b^x` is the same as `log(b)Y = x` (log of `Y`, with base `b`)

Your formula above is the same as:

Y = (log(100e)97.5))/.25

(Read aloud, that's log of 97.5, with base 100e, divided by .25

So, Y = 3.268305672

(Bonus points for someone who can tell me how to format this so the `Log` looks correct)

Comment: ++ for doing the math.

Comment: I should have specified, I know the math bit *sigh. I need to compute hundreds of these and I wanted to know how to do it on solver instead

Comment: @user5498276 - Why not just set some cells equal to each part of your formula? Like, A1 can be `100`, B1 can be `=Exp(1)`, C1 can be .25, etc.  Just set up the spreadsheet like a piece of paper?

Comment: @user5498276 - "I need to compute hundreds of these" ... does that mean you will be setting it up in VBA?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit ambiguous what you're asking...

- Literal math interpretation: 100*(e^0.25)*y = 97.5

  Then y = 97.5 / ( 100 * exp(.25)) = .759
- My guess of what you want: 100*e^(0.25*y) = 97.5

  Then y = ln(97.5/100) / .25 = -.101
- Another possibility: (100 * e)^(0.25 * y) = 97.5

  Then y = (ln(97.5) / ln(100*e)) / .25 = 3.268

Whatever it is, this doesn't need solver!

Comment: Agreed - however the formula should be, I think solver is overkill (and also, it robs OP of learning how to solve this, or change exponents into logs, etc....so if this is a homework question, it's certainly better to learn what to do, instead of simply throwing it into Excel).

Answer (score 1):

The question is "How do I solve this exponential equation on Excel Solver?" which is a fair enough question, as it points to trying to understand how to set up solver.

My interpretation of the equation provided is given in this screenshot ...

[image]

The solver dialog box is then setup as follows ...

[image]

Of note:

- This is a non-linear equation and needs GRG Nonlinear. If you choose LP Simplex, it will not pass the linearity test.
- Ensure "Make Unconstrained Variables Non-Negative" is not checked.

It provided this result for me ...

[image]

A more precise answer can be obtained by decreasing the "Convergence" value on the GRG Non-Linear Options dialog.

---

A problem this simple can also be solved using Goal Seek.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are the only one who actually understood what I was trying to do..One question, is 5 a guess estimate? But is far away from actual value

Comment: Yes, 5 is just any number. Solver routines often work better when the starting point is far from the solution.

Comment: I used to leave that cell empty and hence never got it to work..But thanks again I didnt think of suggesting a guesstimate. I will make sure to suggest an extreme value in my other calculations with solver